# UPDATE with two INNER JOINS giving error "multi-part identifier could not be bound"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL statement that performs an update after two tables are joined. The SET statement is giving me an error that the multi-part identifier could not be bound. I am thinking it is because I don't reference that table anywhere else but I am not sure where to put it. I can't join it because I am just using tbl_TXEX_IRSS as a lookup table to change a code. Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE [PAYROLL].[dbo].[TEMPBILLING]
SET [TEMPBILLING].Pay_Code = [tbl_TXEX_IRSS].tax_irss_code
FROM [PAYROLL].[dbo].[TEMPBILLING] 
INNER JOIN [PAYROLL].[dbo].[ISP-BASIC]
ON [ISP-BASIC].Form_ID = [TEMPBILLING].ISP_Data_ID
INNER JOIN [PAYROLL].[dbo].[TAX-EXEMPT]
ON SUBSTRING([ISP-BASIC].Employee_ID,4,10) = [TAX-EXEMPT].Sage_ID
WHERE
 [ISP-BASIC].ISP_Program like '%IRSS%'
and [ISP-BASIC].Billable='Yes'
and Status='In Prep'
```

Comment: I don't see a join to `[tbl_TXEX_IRSS]`. You need this if you are going to use it in your `SET` operation

Answer (score 2):

The only unqualified column is:

```
and Status = 'In Prep'
```

I imagine `Status` is in multiple tables.  Qualify *all* column names. Shorter table aliases would make the table easier to write and to read.

As for the table name `tbl_TXEX_IRSS`.  That needs to be in a `FROM` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I qualified the column name but I still have the error on the SET statement. The error highlights the [tbl_TXEX_IRSS] as multi-part identifier cannot be bound.

Comment: Because you didn't join to `[tbl_TXEX_IRSS]` in your code. You need to do that

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was able to make aliases for my tables and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, whereas unknown information is pseudo-coded with `<Alias>.<Column>`:

```
UPDATE billing
SET billing.Pay_Code = TxexIrss.tax_irss_code
FROM [dbo].[TEMPBILLING] billing
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ISP-BASIC] IspBasic ON IspBasic.Form_ID = billing.ISP_Data_ID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TAX-EXEMPT] TaxExempt ON SUBSTRING(IspBasic.Employee_ID,4,10) = TaxExempt.Sage_ID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_TXEX_IRSS] TxexIrss ON <Alias>.<Column> = TxexIrss.<Colum>
WHERE (IspBasic.ISP_Program LIKE '%IRSS%') AND (IspBasic.Billable='Yes') AND (Status='In Prep');
```

Your normalization leaves also space for improvement. Consider changing the `Billable` column to a `BIT NOT NULL` with a default value and `Status` to an `INT NOT NULL`, referencing a little table where all possible states are defined. But the most costly one is `IspBasic.ISP_Program LIKE '%IRSS%'`. There should be a `BIT NOT NULL` called `IsIrss` or an `INT NOT NULL` called `ProgramType` or the like in table `IspBasic`, holding this information. Cutting a piece out of a string and comparing it - that can't be indexed, that needs a full table scan.

Comment: I also recommend to omit the database name. Put that in the connection string, that allows you to run you application against differently named DBs ("Payroll", "Payroll_Dev", "Payroll_Int") whatever.